# Permission denied after granting permissions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

I'm currently having an issue with runtime permissions while using the HiPermission library.I'm asking the user to grant the permission to read/write external storage but even though I accept the permission I still get this error when I try to open an image from the gallery. When the application starts there is a permission check to see if the user has accepted the permissions.To access the image the user need to use a button which also has a permission check

```
private boolean checkAllPermissions(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            String[] requestedPermissions = new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                     Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
            for (String permission : requestedPermissions) {
                permissionCheck = permissionCheck + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission);
            }
            if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                makeText(getActivity(),R.string.actvt_main_tst_request_permission_all, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is the error I get:

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Download/download.png (Permission denied)

It's weird though because if I restart the application everything works fine.

```
public void requestAllPermissions(){

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            List<PermissionItem> permissionItems = new ArrayList<PermissionItem>();
            permissionItems.add(new PermissionItem(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, "Camera", R.drawable.permission_ic_camera));
            permissionItems.add(new PermissionItem(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, "Storage", R.drawable.permission_ic_storage));
            HiPermission.create(MainActivity.this)
                    .title("Welcome to App")
                    .msg(getString(R.string.permis_req))
                    .permissions(permissionItems)
                    .animStyle(R.style.PermissionAnimScale)
                    .checkMutiPermission(new PermissionCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClose() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onClose");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "They cancelled our request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            Log.wtf("finished","finished");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions requested completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDeny(String permission, int position) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onDeny");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onGuarantee(String permission, int position) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onGuarantee");
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: Are you waiting until the permissions have been granted to try and access that file? Or are you doing it immediately after calling your `requestAllPermissions()` method?

Comment: Why are you using the `HiPermission` library to request permissions?

Comment: Yes I am,I'm accessing the file manually right after I accept the permissions.

Comment: Hello Gaurav, I did like the animation of it and the way it looks but even before using it the result was the same.The guy before me set the application that way so it would automatically restart after accepting the permissions so I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but your code is not going to pause and wait while the permissions are being requested, so if you're calling `requestAllPermissions()`, and then trying to use that file right after that call, that's why it's not granted yet.

Comment: Sorry about that I probably didn't understand your question.I mean the application asks the permissions first and when the user accepts them they can access the main screen.From the main screen they can upload an image but the user have to accept the permissions first since they are in front of the main screen.

Comment: I'm not really following you, but I still suspect that you might be trying to access that file too quickly. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the user must press a button to open the gallery and select the image. He can't press the button if he has not accepted the permissions since.  I've also set a permission check on the button so he can't open the gallery if he declined the permissions.

Comment: I'm not an Android expert, but I suspect your logic in `checkAllPermissions` may be wrong... you start with `int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` and then _add_ ('+') in the result of each call to `checkSelfPermission()`. If `PERMISSION_GRANTED` is `true` or `1`, and `checkSelfPermission()` returns `true`/`1` or `false`/`0`, then you will always _think_ you have all permissions even if they haven't been granted. You probably want something like `permissionCheck = permissionCheck && ...`. This may then demonstrate the problem MikeM thinks you have... [cont]

Comment: [cont] which I think boils down to that `requestAllPermissions()`will return immediately, before any permissions have been checked/asked/confirmed. If/when the user allows the permissions, the function `public void onFinish()` will be called, and it is _from there_ (either directly, or by calling a callback function that you pass in) where you can now make use of those permissions.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, i was really tired while asking the question and apparently I did not point many things. The checkAllPermissions executes when the user presses the button to capture or upload an image while the requestAllPermissions executes when the application launches. I think I am missing a function for the result of the permission request? I am not sure. Thanks for he answer though.